# Indoor and outdoor TV location remote control issue

Tags: television, remote-control

Does anyone know if televisions usually share the same code for power when transmitting on a remote?  I have a location on a covered patio that I would like to place a TV that is near a wall mounted TV indoors.   Using the Toshiba FireTV remote does indeed accidentally control the indoor TV when outdoors.   My concern is if I order another identical, or even a Roku TV that I will have that issue.   Any way to ensure remotes are 1-to-1 for a given television?

Comment: the Toshiba remote will very likely control most Toshiba TVs ... i doubt that it will control devices from other manufacturers

Comment: My experience is that remotes, even from the same manufacturer but for different models, are almost never fully compatible. Would a universal remote control help? See https://www.cnet.com/news/best-universal-remote-in-2020/ . Prices range from~US$12 on up.